# Disable multiline statements with c/c++ macro

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to disable chunks of code with c/c++ preprocessor depending on some definition, without instrumenting code with `#ifdef #endif`?

```
 // if ENABLE_TEST_SONAR is not defined, test code will be eliminated by preprocessor
 TEST_BEGIN(SONAR)
   uint8_t sonar_range = get_sonar_measurement(i);
   TEST_ASSERT(sonar_range < 300)
   TEST_ASSERT(sonar_range > 100)
 TEST_END
```

Functionally equivalent to something as follows:

```
#ifdef TEST_SONAR
    serial_print("test_case sonar:\r\n");
    uint8_t sonar_range = get_sonar_measurement(i);
    serial_print("  test sonar_range < 300:%d\r\n", sonar_range < 300);
    serial_print("  test sonar_range > 100:%d\r\n", sonar_range > 100);
#endif TEST_SONAR
```

Comment: Why? That's literally what `#ifdef` is for......... talk about re-inventing the wheel....

Comment: I also need to add some extra functionality to TEST_BEGIN, so just wanted to make it in a single line.

Comment: can you be a little more concise with 'disable'? You mean generate the code, link it, but not execute it?

Comment: @DikobrAz: Such as? You did not state that in your question.

Comment: ideally to entirely cut it out with preprocessor

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit elaborated in question

Comment: Much better thanks. How about using functions??

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's time critical system, so probably I can enable only few tests at a time. That's why I'm considering preprocessor for enabling and disabling tests.

Comment: @DikobrAz: You don't have to actually call every function in your codebase on every run of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple lines can be disabled only with `#ifdef` or `#if` but single lines can be disabled with a macro.  Note that multiple lines can be combined with `\`

```
#ifdef DOIT
#define MYMACRO(x) \
 some code \
 more code \
 even more \
#else
#define MYMACRO(x)
#endif
```

Then when you call `MYMACRO` anplace that code will either be included or not based on whether `DOIT` is defined

That's the closest you can come and is used frequently for debugging code

EDIT:  On a whim I tried the following and it seems to work (in MSVC++ and g++):

```
#define DOIT
#ifdef DOIT
#define MYMACRO(x) x
#else
#define MYMACRO(x)
#endif

void foo(int, int, int)
{
}

int main(int, char **)
{
    int x = 7;
MYMACRO(
if (x) 
return 27; 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
    foo(1, 2, 3);
)

}
```

Comment: yes, if I had only one macro to control all tests I would go with this approach, but I probably want to selectively enable and disable tests.

Comment: Thanks, I think solution in edit is just what I should go for.

Answer (score 1):

No, the only way to disable sections of codes **effectively** using preprocessing is by `#ifdef #endif`. Theoretically, you could use `#if identifier`, but it's better to stick to checking whether a variable is defined.

Another option (perhaps) is to use a preprocessing macro:

Edit:

Perhaps using plain functions and `#ifdef` might work better?

```
function test_function() {
  /* Do whatever test */
}
#define TESTING_IDENTIFIER
#define TEST( i, f ) if ((i)) do { f } while (0)
```

Then, for each test, you define a unique identifier and call it by providing the identifier first and the function (with parenthesis) second.

```
TEST( TESTING_IDENTIFIER, test_function() );
```

Finally, `f` can be anything that's syntactically correct -- You don't have to create a function for every test, you can put the code inline.

Comment: I don't think you can put /*, */ in macro

Comment: Aren't macros copied verbatim

Comment: I guess comment removal just goes before macro expansion https://ideone.com/mVgzaU

Comment: Ok, apparently not, but I updaed with alternate solution (I should remove that one)

Answer (score 0):

I will anyway mention an obvious solution of

```
#define DO_TEST_SONAR
#ifdef DO_TEST_SONAR
#define TEST_SONAR if(true) {
#else
#define TEST_SONAR if(false) {
#endif
#define TEST_SONAR_END }

...
TEST_SONAR
code
TEST_SONAR_END
```

The code will still get compiled, not completely removed, but some smart compilers might optimize it out.

UPD: just tested and

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//#define DO_TEST_SONAR
#ifdef DO_TEST_SONAR
#define TEST_SONAR if(true) {
#else
#define TEST_SONAR if(false) {
#endif
#define TEST_SONAR_END }

int main() {
TEST_SONAR
cout << "abc" << endl;
TEST_SONAR_END
}
```

produces absolutely identical binaries with `cout` line commented out and non commented, so indeed the code is stripped. Using g++ 4.9.2 with `-O2`.